# Insert into ##temptable with IF condition

Tags: t-sql

I have to change a procedure in such a way to make it dependable on user ID. The procedure includes several SELECT INTO statements and SELECT statement at the end, which returns data.

I wanted to add IF condition which will check user ID and execute SELECT INTO statement for this condition. However the problem is that there can't be the same tables in two conditions.

One can't execute this code:

```
select '1' as Number into ##temp

 if 1=1

 begin

   select * into ##temp2 from ##temp

 end

 else

 begin

   select * into ##temp2 from ##temp

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just create the structure of the second table first, then insert into it accordingly?

```
select '1' as Number into ##temp
select * into ##temp2 from ##temp where 1=0

if 1=1

begin
    insert into ##temp2 select * from ##temp
end

else

begin
    insert into ##temp2 select * from ##temp
end
```